# GWTP Nested Presenter : Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> Cannot be resolved

Tags: gwt-platform

I'm trying to make the nested presenter in GWT. 
I've been "copy & paste" code from the sample GWTP project @http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/SimpleNestedSample

At one point the code

```
@ContentSlot
public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> contentSlot = new   Type<RevealContentHandler<?>>();
```

gave me error and i am not able to find which package to import by eclipse suggestion to resolve error by Type.
(Been trying all the possible "Type" packages by eclipse suggestion such as
    import com.google.gwt.i18n.server.Type;
    import com.google.gwt.dev.asm.Type;
    import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type;

)

Can anyone tell what package to import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.Type;`